# Is it possible to send a file(an image file) or share your desktop/ viewport with other users using Lync UCWA?

Tags: lync, lync-2013, lync-server-2010, ucwa

I tried to explore the UCWA code but did not understand/ get across any such document or code that informs whether desktop sharing or file sharing is possible using UCWA api?

Kindly inform if this capability is present in UCWA? If it is, kindly share some link/code/documentation regarding the same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The *current* core features of UCWA can be found at: [Core-Features](http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/core-features) which include querying contacts and groups, P2P and multi-party IM, online meeting scheduling, joining an online meeting, contact card (note/presence/location), phone audio, and anonymous meeting join.

Application Sharing / File Sharing (Data Collaboration) is not publicly available in UCWA.  These features have been talked about for a *future* update to Lync Server.